# Помогите скачать чужой лендинг и обойти зажиту

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Я не знаю как правильно скачать себе эту страничку тутми.рф что бы правильно подгрузились все элементы и этот лендингбыл рабочим. Скачиваю его подгружаю js но сайтне рабочий не работает ни прелоадер ни слайд шоу. Помогите правильно подгрузить все файлы что бы все работало
[Скачать исходник](http://swblife.3dn.ru/tutmee.zip)

Comment: Первый секрет: не нужно путать JavaScript и Java. Второй секрет: проще взять и написать с нуля ровно то, что вам нужно, а не разбирать тонны чужого кода. Тем более взятого, можно сказать, незаконно.

Comment: При тех технологиях, которые там используются, ты этим кодом вряд-ли воспользуешься.

Comment: я с этим осведомлен, легких путей не ищу. Прошу Вас помочь разобраться с данным кодом потому что на обучение моего мозга Java уйдут годы а этот прелоадер могу использовать сейчас. По сей причине делаю вывод что через пару лет когда познаю джаву этот код устареет появятся более свежие варианты  и сам проект не будет уже так востребован,  через данный временный промежуток. Если бы я знал этот язык или имел хотя бы скромный прибор по путешествую во времени, кротовых норах, я бы  не взывал на этом сайте о помощи профессионалов.

Comment: Qwertiy, поведай пожалуйста что там за технологии? может какие-сто ссылки или статьи как обойти

Comment: Там нет джавы. Java и javascript - перпендикулярные языки, у которых только область применения совсем недавно пересеклась.

Comment: @Etki хорошо я это понял, я не настолько принципиален в этом вопросе,  а по делу поможете?

Comment: Боюсь, с вашими текущими знаниями вы действительно не сможете воспользоваться чужими наработками. Там стек из angular, require, jquery и других вещей.

Comment: Лучше возьмите примеры тех фишек которые вы хотите повторить, и попробуйте реализовать сами. Вы получите хороший опыт и удовольствие от готового результата. Ну а для всех затруднений которые у Вас возникнут есть *StackOverflow*))

Comment: @Etki вы мне подскажите может нужно использовать другое ПО а не стандартный браузер для того что бы скачать все файлы.? я знаю точно что если я скачаю все элементы сайта .js .css  и подгружу их у меня все заработает, Как вы со своими проф. знаниями можете скачать этот код?

Comment: @Kirill Ermolov помогите пожалуйста скачать этот код?

Comment: "я знаю точно что если я скачаю все элементы сайта .js .css и подгружу их у меня все заработает" - нет, не обязательно, это не так.

Comment: @Etki а что еще нужно ?поведайте пожалуйста

Comment: Сервер, на котором все это расположено и с которого подтягиваются данные?

Comment: @Etki а с помощью исходного кода сайта?

Comment: Вам уже раз десять сказали, что это затея со стопроцентным провалом. Вы не вытянете исходный код сайта. Если вытянете - то не поднимете. Если даже поднимете - отдельно никакой прелоадер не выцепите. То, что вы собрались делать, на самом деле является преступлением (хотя, конечно, у вас не получится его осуществить).

Comment: Поищите готовые решения с документацией. Их куча.

Answer (score 9):

> Qwertiy, поведай пожалуйста что там за технологии?

Из того, что бросилось в глаза:

- **requirejs** - асинхронная подгрузка модулей скриптов. Как правило используется при разделении на модули-сущности для загрузки только тех сущностей, которые нужны на данной странице.
- **AngularJS** - весьма крупный и мощный MVC-фреймвёрк, используемый, преимущественно, для создания крупных одностраничных приложений. Перестраивает dom-дерево на основе директив. В том примере анимации связаны в ним.
- Что-то для работы с svg от Adobe и не только.

Ну и заодно:

- **jQuery**
- **modernizr** - библиотека для определения возможностей браузера.
- Что-то для кроссбраузерной анимации.

> и разобрать его по частям

На основе качества минимизации скриптов, я бы поставил под вопрос и качество их кода. Но разбирать его мне лень.

> на обучение моего мозга Java уйдут годы а этот прелоадер могу использовать сейчас

Javascript и Java - это разные языки. Пора понять. Или тебя тоже можно называть не Виталием, а Талией (есть такое женское имя)?

> а этот прелоадер могу использовать сейчас

Не можешь. И никто не станет. Чтобы по работающему сайту (не исходникам) понять, как оно работает, надо потратить в разы больше времени и обладать куда более значительным пониманием всех используемых технологий, чем для того, чтобы просто это реализовать с нуля.

> я знаю точно что если я скачаю все элементы сайта .js .css и подгружу их у меня все заработает

Нет. Есть ещё шаблоны (части разметки). К тому же, там ещё и данные откуда-то запрашиваются вероятно.

А ещё, то, что ты выложил похоже на страницу с уже отработавшими скриптами, а не на исходники.

> может нужно использовать другое ПО а не стандартный браузер для того что бы скачать все файлы.

Fiddler позволит отследить все http-запросы. Если постараться (либо, если повезёт с сайтом), то их помещение в автоматический ответ позволит локально получить работающую версию в тех же объёмах, которыми ты воспользуешься на сайте для её получения. Потом можно попытаться подменить это на файлы и получить что-то приближённое к исходникам. Естественно, скрипты для получения данных от бекенда придётся при этом переписать (но, вероятно, для предоадера они не слишком важны).

> на самом деле является преступлением

Не факт. Библиотеки там открытые, а если удастся выковырять прелоадер, то от оригинального кода сайта при этом вряд ли останется что-то существенное, за что можно было бы зацепиться.

Comment: то что я выложил скачал вчера, не знал что этот вопрос такой проблематичный полагал что есть какая-та процедура и понятийный аппарат по скачиванию чужого кода

Comment: @Виталий, я дополнил ответ в этом плане. Но вообще-то, код принято писать или искать в репозиториях, а не таскать чужой.

Comment: спасибо большое за ответ, жму руку. Ведать у меня искаженное представление о приятном. Я в основном таскаю код с themfores разбираю по запчастям а потом леплю из 3-4 сайтов что-то свое не всегда правда удается скачать исходный код сайта, это как раз тот случай

Answer (score 2):

Таких прелоадеров - вагон и маленькая тележка по всему интернету. С исходниками, API, примерами и документацией. Воспользуйтесь ими (ну вот например - http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/PagePreloadingEffect/), вместо того, чтобы тратить время на попытки вытащить и разобрать чужой код.

У нас на проекте используется PreloadJS, если я не ошибаюсь, доступен бесплатно, выглядит вот так: https://www.branchtrack.com/projects/wjd218zf